# vim diff view for long lines

Tags: neovim

Is there a solution for getting a useful vim diff with very long lines? The problem I have is that for example I have one long line in one file:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

In another file I have a line very similar, but I have two changes. I capitalize ipsum to IPSUM and Duis to DUIS.

```
Lorem IPSUM dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. DUIS aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

The problem is that now, when I compare these two files with :diffthis, vimdiff highlights everything between IPSUM and DUIS, and this is really useless to look at. I would like to just see highlighted LOREM and DUIS and their lowercase counterparts. Here is an image of what my vimdiff view looks like.[image] Is there a way to achieve this?

The behaviour I want is actually the default diff view in pycharm. This image is from pycharm:[image]

Comment: It looks like that plugin allows you to use the patience algorithm and hist alorithm, but atleast in the vim I am using (neovim 0.4.2), there is already an option to set the diff algorithm:
set diffopt=algorithm:histogram
or
set diffopt=algorithm:patience
will set the diff algorithm, I've tried both of these and they dont help in the case I explained.

Answer (score 1):

I found a plugin that does what I am asking for:
https://github.com/rickhowe/diffchar.vim